# InvalidOperationException в Unity при вызове GetProcessesByName

Tags: c#, unity3d, mono

Проверяю запущен ли стим

```
if (Process.GetProcessesByName("Steam").FirstOrDefault() != null) {
    Debug.Log("Steam запущен");
    return;
}
Debug.Log("Steam не запущен");
```

Steam запущен, но получаю ошибку:

> InvalidOperationException: Process has exited, so the requested
>   information is not available.

```
try {
    var procList = Process.GetProcesses();
    if (procList.Any(t => string.Equals(t.ProcessName, "Steam"))) {
        Debug.Log("Steam enable");
        return;
    }

    Debug.Log("Steam disable");

} catch (Exception e) {
    Debug.Log(e);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`GetProcessesByName` моновский вызывает `GetProcesses`, который внутри итерирует список. Для части процессов в системе нельзя получить имя и метод выбрасывает исключение.

Рекомендую вам самому прогонять этот список:

```
var procList = Process.GetProcesses();
for (int i = 0; i < procList.Length; i++) {
    try {
        if(string.Equals(procList[i].ProcessName, "Steam") {
             Debug.Log("Steam запущен");
             return;
        }
    } catch {}
}

Debug.Log("Steam не запущен");
```

Comment: Добавил в вопрос ваш код,немного переписав.Все равно получаю данную ошибку

Comment: @Максим `try` внутри `for` должен быть, чтоб отбросить случаи, когда не получается имя получить.

Comment: а если мне вернуть нужно будит bool?при исключение сразу false возращает